# I want to get Arced/Curved jquery plugin plugin to run offline

Tags: jquery

I have found this jQuery plugin: http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js For jQuery 1.7.1

And i can use it to get curved text but it needs permanent internet-connectivity,
is there anway to do it offline?

Answer (score 2):

Download the files and have them be local. Instead of a link to the js files.